# Why can't I see the results of the query in protege4?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege4

I knew this might be a stupid question but I don't know the answer :)

I am using [protege4](http://protege.stanford.edu/download/registered.html) I built my ontology and when I tried to use DL Query from the DL query tap in protege4 it executes fine and I get results.

However, when I click "Add to ontology" to add my query to the ontology it adds it but without any query results!!! Why are there no query results? and how to see it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First some terminology:

- Every **OWL ontology** is a **set of OWL axioms**.
- Every **DL-Query** is an **OWL class expression**.
- Every **DL-Query result** is a **set of OWL entitie**s.

You can only add axioms to an ontology. You cannot add class expressions nor sets of entities to an OWL ontology.

The "Add to ontology" button seems to create a new *EquivalentClasses*-axiom on the basis of the query (i.e. class expression), and a named class (given by the user), and then asserts this axiom into the active ontology, i.e.

```
EquivalentClasses(new_name query)
```

(I didn't quite get it working like this in my version of Protege 4, but such a functionality would make sense.)

The current OWL2 specification does not say anything about how to store class expressions and query results in the ontology. These have to be specified and calculated every time from scratch after you load the ontology from the file.